# How to stop the emission of particles for an amount of frames, and then continue?

Tags: particles

In my animation wondering if there's any way for me to stop the emission of particles for an amount of frames then continue. If there isn't anyway could someone please give me a suggestion that will give the same effect because all I've thought of so far is replacing the emitter

Comment: Maybe add two different particle systems, each starting at different frames

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple particle systems to the same object, each one with  different start and end frames
[image]